# Negation of a statement about convergence

Tags: logic

How one can negate this statement:

A real sequence converges to a limit $x$ if and only if every subsequence also converges to the limit $x$.

Comment: The negation of "Every x is P" is "Some x is **not** P".

Comment: Aren't you asking for the contrapositive ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: No. logical negation.

Answer (score 1):

I see no better *negation* than

"It is false that a real sequence converges to a limit $x$ if and only if every subsequence also converges to the limit $x$."

A logically equivalent one is

"A real sequence converges to a limit $x$ and some subsequence does not converge to the limit $x$, or, a real sequence does not converges to a limit $x$ and every subsequence converges to the limit $x$."

Both are equivalent to *false*.

Answer (score -1):

We can negate as follows

$$\lnot(A\iff B) \equiv A\iff \lnot B$$

that is

*a real sequence converge to a limit x if and only if exists a subsequence which doesn't converge to the limit x*

Comment: This is not the negation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah ok! I gave a contrapositive! I fix